# can we use custom sms getway for message sending in parse server?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using parse server as backend for my app. after registration I want to verify users mobile number for that I want to use free sms getway. any one know how can we do that?

appreciate for help.

Comment: What are you asking? You want a suggestion for a free sms gateway?, if so this is off-topic for stack overflow. If you are looking for the code on how to send the SMS then you will need to post some code where you show us what you have tried.

Comment: I want to write custom webservice for parse.com. while save data on parse.com exicute this service and send verification code on users mobile number @rckoenes

Comment: That is way to broad of an question and are just requirements, Try and build it yourself and if you are stuck post your question here with the code you are stuck on.

Comment: @rckoenes can u send me some useful link for do that?

Comment: No, I can not, since I have not idea about the system yo-u will be using. You will need to do your own research on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the API libraries for resources on how to integrate your web service:

https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries

Without further information on what language you are using, what you have tried, or even what gateway you are using, it is impossible to give a more detailed answer.